# Which tools simplify administration tasks with Docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Context:** My task is to administer a virtual machine with about 5 web services for a small workgroup. I plan to run all services in Docker containers. An additional nginx Docker container should redirect requests to the different services.

**Problem:** I do not have much experience with DevOps and plan to use basic bash scripts and Docker Compose to administer the setup.

**Question:** Which tools simplify this administration task (updating, backup, exchanging containers, changing port directives)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single virtual machine with 6 Docker containers does not require any tool. Adding tooling to the mix really just increase the complexity level of your installation and turns a simple thing into a monster.

A few Shell scripts is all you need at that size.

Answer (score 2):

While what ETL says in his answer is more or less true, I still think there some value in some tooling to ale life raider.

What I’ve found is [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/), which would let you do most of what you want with a nice web interface.